# How to add button with onclick while sending email using smtp?

Tags: c#, smtp

Hey guys i'm generating a email in my backend to be  sent to the user and my mail body consists of button which has a onclick event, and in that onclick event i will be using `location.href` to navigate the user to my desired location, but the problem is when i bind the onclick event in the backend it doesn't get reflected in the mail, other things such as value and style attribute get added but the onclick attribute is not getting added, the code is

`<input type="button" onclick="location.href='https://wwww.test.com/';"  value="test" style='background-color: #00a948;top: 0;padding: 9px 20px;color: #fff;border: none;border-radius: 50px;'>`

Thanks

Comment: why not simply style a regular `<a href` to look like a button, instead of mucking about with javascript? which _nobody_ wants in an email in the first place?

Comment: i will definitely consider that but is it possible to have a normal button over there?

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the code is above when i send that out what i receive is ```<input type="button" value"test" style="....">``` i'm not getting the onclick that i am sending